# How to put string in edittext from expandable listView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an expandable list of contact numbers and also an editText. I want to set editText with the item that user click from expandable list.I can get the value of item via toast.But I can not setText to editText. I don't find any right way to do that. 
Here is code:

```
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private final SparseArray<Group> groups;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;
    public Activity activity;
    FormEditText recip;

    public MyExpandableListAdapter(Activity act, SparseArray<Group> groups) {
        activity = act;
        this.groups = groups;
        inflater = act.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition).children.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String children = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        TextView text = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_details, null);
        }

        text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text.setText(children);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("children",children);
                //TODO
                Toast.makeText(activity, children,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition).children.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_group, null);
        }
        Group group = (Group) getGroup(groupPosition);
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(group.string);
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to get the value to your activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((SelfSms)activity).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            text.setText(children);
        }
    });
```

Use this,

```
        ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        MyExpandableListAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(this,groups);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                String children = groups.get(groupPosition).children.get(childPosition);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        phone.setText(children );
                    }
                });

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Also add

```
      android:focusable="false"; 
      android:clickable="false";
```

To your textview in child layout

Comment: Can you please explain where to put it?

Comment: https://unsee.cc/disumeta/

Please,check the link.When user click on subitem,it will show on recipient field.

Comment: As I mention,I don't know the way to setText on editText from expandable listview....see the imagelink below.
[link](https://ibb.co/fR2U1Q)

Comment: in the same activity... expandable listview  and editText both are in same layout.Just one after another...

Comment: Here to put this code?This is showing error...


        expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            recip.setText(MyExpandableListAdapter.children);

            return false;
        }
    });

Comment: Let me show you my full code of my activity...
[activity](https://ideone.com/6hPKhy) and also [MyExpandableListAdapter](https://ideone.com/jBmbs7)

Comment: Actually,I am getting the value from list.I can also separate the number.My problem is I can not put that value in the editText when item is clicked. :(

Comment: I am getting value inside this.
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("children",children);
              Toast.makeText(activity, children,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
I want to put that value in the editText.

Comment: Sir,sorry for late reply.I used the code in the onCreate.But I am not getting any log response.I also tried commenting convertview.setOnClickListener block.

Comment: [Activity code](https://ideone.com/xYvQSZ) and [adpter code](https://ideone.com/oun56S)

Comment: no response from that log.I commented  Entire convertView.setOnClickListener.

Comment: I think debuger can not enter into the listView.setOnChildClickListener block. there is no response from debug when i click on the item

Comment: this is same.I just put it into a method.However,i tried so as u said.But not worked though.... :(

Comment: @Avijit  setfocusable="false" and clickable="false" for the textview in child layout

Comment: After Doing the above change and debug and lemme know. If you get the click response in Childclicklistener

Comment: After doing so,there is another problem appears.list data are gone.